# UICollectionview footer in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to add footer to a `UICollectionView`using this code. i am using Using Custom Layout in UICollectionView layout

Added delegate and datasource methods :-

`UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Code in `viewdDidLoad()` function :-

```
 UINib(nibName: "ProfileFooter", bundle:nil)
 collectionView!.registerNib(nibName1, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileFooter")
        collectionView.registerClass(ProfileFooter.classForCoder(), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "ProfileFooter", withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileFooter")

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        var reusable = UICollectionReusableView()

            if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter{
                let ProfileFooter = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileFooter", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                ProfileFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                reusable = ProfileFooter
            }

        return reusable
    }
```

can any one check what is wrong in this ??

Comment: Why have you written both registerNib and registerClass ? remove the line of registerNib.

Comment: I have checked with both still its not working ...

Comment: Write registerClass line like this : `registerClass(ProfileFooter, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileFooter")` and also check once again for identifier of footer view is correct or not.

Comment: I have tried that also ... Not working

Comment: please see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343367/ios-programmatically-collectionview-with-custom-headers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655652/how-to-make-both-header-and-footer-in-collection-view-with-swift

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to cast your footer view while dequeuing.
Try this.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
switch kind
 {
  case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
      let profileFooter = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileFooter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileFooter
      profileFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
      return profileFooter
  case default:
      assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
 }
}
```

Comment: I am usinng custom layout in collectionview

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what isn't working in your code. I recognised the footer isn't being cast. If you could provide more detail it would be helpful!