# Swift - creating collectionView without Storyboard initWithFrame error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am creating a collectionView without a storyboard - removed it from my project.

I create it here, in AppDelegate. My footer and header are dequeued correctly, I have zero cells displaying as images are loading, but I cannot figure out where this method initWithFrame is called! Any help appreciated.

***NOT USING STORYBOARD***

called inside app delegate

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let myTabBar = TabBarVC()
window.rootViewController = myTabBar
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
let homeVC = HomeVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
myTabBar.present(homeVC, animated: false)
```

This ultimately fails with the following error:

```
2018-06-26 16:02:15.379473-0700 MMDH[62033:2946934] -[MMDH.HomeVC 
initWithFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcce82f400
2018-06-26 16:02:15.389976-0700 MMDH[62033:2946934] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MMDH.HomeVC 
initWithFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcce82f400
```

I have my Cell, Footer, Header all dequeued. I cannot figure out where this is erroring... Heres setup code:

```
class HomeVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var headerVC = HeaderView()
var footerVC = homeFooterView()

var photos = [Photo]()
var imageFetchOperationQueue = OperationQueue()
var infoOperationQueue = OperationQueue()

let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (width / 3), height: (width / 3))
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width / 2)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

    if photos.count == 0 {
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    } else if photos.count < 9 {
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    } else {
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self

    collectionView?.register(HomeVC.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "homeVC")
    self.view.addSubview(headerVC)
    collectionView?.register(homeFooterView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footerVC")
    self.view.addSubview(footerVC)
    collectionView?.register(HomePicCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues in your `viewDidLoad` method.

1. Your primary issue is registering your `HomeVC` class as the header view type. You want to use `HeaderView.self`, not `HomeVC.self`.
2. Do not base the layout on screen size. Your collection view may not take up the entire screen. Base the layout on the size of the collection view. Also note that the size could change. It's best to update the layout in the `viewWillTransition` method.
3. This is a UICollectionViewController. You should not be creating your own `UICollectionView`. It will be done for you before `viewDidLoad` is called. Remove the three lines that create the collection view and set the `dataSource` and `delegate`.

Minor but your `homeFooterView` class should be named `HomeFooterView`. Class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy, I've tried your solution and it still doesn't work - get the same error. i've followed the guide here, and this works (it's the same setup). could this be due to some label or uiimageview I havent initialized? 

it sounds like the HomeVC itself isnt initializing with a frame..?

Comment: So you changed the line `collectionView?.register(HomeVC.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "homeVC")` to `collectionView?.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "homeVC")`? If you did that and still have the problem, update your question with the stack trace showing where the crash is happening.

Comment: these changes are happening while interacting with UICollectionReusableView. I've gotten all my code to work except this. I've tried adding in the methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343367/ios-programmatically-collectionview-with-custom-headers

Comment: any thoughts on why this is happening? Can't seem to get the frame to work, and this is only when Im using headers/footers... theyre empty as well

Comment: You didn't reply to my previous comment.

Comment: thanks for your help, i solved this though. If you answer Ill give you a check because you did help me with other issues. The issue was I was registering my header/footer then calling self.view.addsubview(header) and ther was no frame.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `addSubview` at all to add the header or footer.